# need to convert Verilog graycode function into vhdl

Tags: vhdl

First the Verilog:

```
function [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] gray_conv;
    input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] in;
begin
    gray_conv = {in[ADDR_WIDTH-1],
         in[ADDR_WIDTH-2:0] ^ in[ADDR_WIDTH-1:1]};
end
endfunction
```

Here's my attempt to convert Verilog gray code function into vhdl:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bus_fifo_async is
    generic(
        ADDR_WIDTH                : integer := 3;   
        DATA_WIDTH                : integer := 32
    );
    port(
        wr_rst_i                  : in    std_logic;
        wr_clk_i                  : in    std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of fifty_shades_of_vhdl is

    function gray_conv(din: std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0))
        return std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0) is
    begin
        return ( din(ADDR_WIDTH-1) & (din(ADDR_WIDTH-2 downto 0) 
            xor din(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 1)));
    end function;
begin

end architecture;
```

VHDL Compiler "barfs" at me... says ##$@#$.vhdl:44:35: index constraint not allowed here.

Comment: Your code has a couple of syntax errors: 2x entity declarations, extra ; at end of port list.

Comment: A function declaration has a return value type mark and no subtype indication. Here simply remove the subtype indication or create a subtype of std_logic_vector to use as the type mark. You can also [derive the subtype from the parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa3TL.jpg) using the LENGTH attribute of an array object the way you used ADDR_WIDTH in the function. The advantage is a function that works for any length parameter. Please provide a [mcve] which allows readers to replicate the issue as well as verify answers.

Comment: Tricky, ok, i fixed it.  sorry, i was trying to cut and paste all the extra VHDL code needed and didn't check it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that VHDL requires that when returning a std_logic_vector from a function the return length of the std_logic_vector is unconstrained.   This is a difference from verilog that requires a constrained return type from a function.

"return std_logic_vector" instead of "return std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0)"

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bus_fifo_async is
    generic(
        ADDR_WIDTH                : integer := 3;   
        DATA_WIDTH                : integer := 32
    );
    port(
        wr_rst_i                  : in    std_logic;
        wr_clk_i                  : in    std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of fifty_shades_of_vhdl is

    function gray_conv(din: std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0))
        return std_logic_vector is
    begin
        return ( din(ADDR_WIDTH-1) & (din(ADDR_WIDTH-2 downto 0) 
            xor din(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 1)));
    end function;
begin

end architecture;
```